# Javascript slideUp / slideDown / one button

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble of solving a problem. I have 2 buttons, the one is for slideUp and the other is for slideDown. What i would like to do is to have one button that toggle instead of having 2.

Thanks.

I have this code in html:

```
<div id = "box">Show / Hide</div>
  <button onclick="slideUp('box');">Slide Up</button>
  <button onclick="slideDown('box');">Slide Down</button>
```

and i have this code in css:

```
body{
  background:grey;
}

#box{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:orange;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:3%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

and my javascript code is this:

```
function slideUp(el) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  elem.style.transition = "all 2s ease-in-out";
  elem.style.height = "0px";
}
function slideDown(el) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  elem.style.transition = "all 2s ease-in-out";
  elem.style.height = "400px";
}
```

Comment: I actually was looking for the implementation as two separate functions for a demo and I thought your code would work,  but it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create **CSS** `class` with the `height:0` rule, and *toggle* that class with **JS**:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("box");
function slide() {
  elem.classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.hide {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="slide();">Slide Toggle</button>
<div id="box" class="box">Show / Hide</div>
```

Comment: Every time you click, the DOM must be analyzed. This gets expensive over time.

Comment: `transition : all 2s ease-in-out` doesn't have to be set in js.

Comment: @Bosworth99: "Every time the user clicks" is not very expensive. They don't do that a thousand times per second.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Its expensive enough, and shouldn't be promoted as a good design pattern. These clicks tend to do more and more as an application grows in complexity. My humble $.02

Comment: @itsgoingdown hey in line one of your CSS it needs to be "#box" because box is the ID not the class. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Put the css properties into a class, add the class to your element, and then toggle the class that affect the height on/off of the element using [classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
function slideToggle(el) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(el);
  elem.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
body{
  background:grey;
}

#box{
  width:400px;
  background:orange;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:3%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slider {
    transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
    height:0px;
}
.slider.open {
    height:400px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "box" class="slider">Show / Hide</div>
<button onclick="slideToggle('box');">Slide</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to track state with a simple boolean, a bit like so :

```
var _bool = false;
var _box = document.getElementById('box');
var _clik = document.getElementById('clik');

_clik.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (_bool){
      _box.style.height = '100px';
      _bool = false;
   } else {
      _box.style.height = '10px';
      _bool = true;
   }

});
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwvjb66z/)

Importantly, we're not storing state on the DOM, and so once your app gets complicated, it will stay performant. You, obviously, can use these two states in whatever way you like (animation, css transition, etc);

Answer (score 2):

You can create class `.slideup`

```
#box.slideUp {
    height:0;
}
```

And toggle this class on #box:

```
function toggle(){
    document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('slideUp')
}
```

Example [here](http://codepen.io/frontendguy/pen/dMyzeN)

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to toggle a class on the box when the button is clicked. That class will set the `height` on the box to 0, and so the transition will take effect and smooth the change.

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('.js-button').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  document.querySelector('.box').classList.toggle('box-closed')
});
```

**CSS**

```
.box-closed {
  height: 0px;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/frqL4dvq/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply transition to  #box via css stylesheet;

```
 #box {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:orange;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:3%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

I am trying to get more familiar with modules today, so this is a modular approach - solution

```
  var Dropdown = function(el) {

      var is_open = false;
      var elem = document.querySelector(el);  
      // in case you cannot set transition via stylesheet 
      elem.style.transition = "all 2s ease-in-out";

      function slideUp() {
        elem.style.height = "0px";     
        is_open = false;
      }
      function slideDown() {
        elem.style.height = "400px";
        is_open = true;
      }
      function init() {
        if(is_open) {
          slideUp();
        }else{
          slideDown();
        }
      }
      return {
        init : init
      }
  };

  myDropdown = Dropdown('#box');
  document.querySelector('#your-button').addEventListener('click',  myDropdown.init);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it shorter:

```
<button onclick="slide()"></button>

<div id="box"></div>
```

**JS:** `slide(){document.getElementById("box").classList.toggle('hide');}`

```
#box {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hide {
  height: 0px !important;
}
```